# Should it be possible to create a 64 bit / 32 bit wrapper extension?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, windbg

Some WinDbg extensions are only available as 32 Bit. If I would

- write a 64 bit extension for WinDbg
- write a 32 bit application (executable) which communicates with the 64 bit extension
- 1:1 forward all calls of the DbgEng API from the 64 bit extension to the executable

Should it then be possible to reuse the 32 bit plugin on 64 bit WinDbg?

The assumption is, that it does not need to deal with pointers, just help in string processing (execute commands on the debugger and parse its text output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not post a comment, so post an answer. It is a answer to your comment above

If you want to use x86 proxy process to run x86 windbg plugin, you will have the same limitation for debugging: your proxy process will not be able to attach to x64 application

Comment: I want to write a 64 bit extension, so it will run in 64 bit WinDbg. Then I do some inter-process communication to talk to a 32 bit executable. The 32 bit application would forward the calls to the 32 bit WinDbg extension. If that would work, I can use 64 bit WinDbg.

Comment: I think it is too hard. You will need to intercept all Debug Engine call in the x86 plugine and redirect them with all parameters back to x64 windbg, execute in x64 enviroment and return result back to x86 windbg. You can try to do OLE server with Debug Engine interfaces and do work by means MIDL + RPC.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more easy to use x86 windbg. Debugging tools for windows have the both.

Comment: Use WinDbg x86 to debug 64 bit applications? That doesn't work: "Could not attach to process 3004, NTSTATUS 0xC00000BB", so I have to use WinDbg x64.